# Set redious of a specific location for android alarm

Tags: android

I am trying to make a location based alarm android app. I have a location lat=23.47393747, lng=90.26383636. how to make a 50 meter redious of this place?  and how to check if my current location  is within this redious or not.?

Comment: you basically need to check distance between 2 GPS coordinates - your current and your target. And if it is <50 meters - do your alarm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GeoFence to set up a radius of 50 meters alarming area as well as detect if someone is in the fence. Please refer this link for document and sample:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html